# Database connection in Expression Engine

Tags: php, expressionengine

I am starting to learn expression engine cms.
in this,I want to fetch some data from database manually in expression engine.
please tell me how can we give database connection and how to get data from database.

if you have any links regarding this ..please share that one to me..

thank you.

Comment: why devote the post ..please tell me..

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'm voting to close. The reason for both is that this question is too broad and too vague for this site's format. Stack Overflow is neither a help forum nor a discussion forum, it's a Q&A resource, for specific questions about coding that can have definite correct answers. Request for tutorials, pointers, general advice, and broad overviews are off-topic here. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page to get a better understanding of the site's format, and this [advice on how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Meaby just start here: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/how_to/building_a_simple_news_site.html

and after building a simple application come with some more detailed (specific) questions, dont wonder why they downvoted You, people here dont like such major questions like:

> How to use X`

Good luck anyway.

Comment: i did that app.can we give manual db connection in expression engine @Uriziel

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this in templates using the bulit-in query module.  Please have a look here at the official documentation:

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/query/

If you are interested in add-on development, the database class section of the documentation has a lot of good information on the matter:

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/database.html